# std::filesystem:file_size send me an incoherent value

Tags: c++, mingw, std-filesystem

In order to read a file in my code, I use std::filesystem::file_size (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size) to get his size. I use this code :

```
template <typename TYPE>
inline void read_binary_file(const fs::path filename, std::vector<TYPE>& result) 
{ 
  std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary); 
  __ERR_READFILE01__ // file cannot be open 
  SPDLOG_DEBUG("Reading {}", filename.u8string()); 
 
  size_t filesize; 
  try
  { 
    filesize = fs::file_size(filename); 
  } 
  catch(fs::filesystem_error& e) 
  { 
    std::cout << e.what() << '\n'; abort(); 
  } 
  assert(filesize%sizeof(TYPE) == 0); 
  SPDLOG_DEBUG("size of file {}", filesize); 
  SPDLOG_DEBUG("size of {}", static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(-1)); 
  SPDLOG_DEBUG("size of type {}", sizeof(TYPE)); 
  SPDLOG_DEBUG("size of the reading vector {}", filesize/sizeof(TYPE));  
  result.resize(filesize/sizeof(TYPE)); 
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(result.data()), filesize); 
  file.close(); 
}
```

This works for most of the files I need to read, but for a file ( ~3 gigas), I have a strange issue :

```
[07/12/2020 11:52:42][debug] size of file 18446744072617361848 
[07/12/2020 11:52:42][debug] size of 18446744073709551615 
[07/12/2020 11:52:42][debug] size of type 4 
[07/12/2020 11:52:42][debug] size of the reading vector 4611686018154340462
```

In the documentation, I can read `The non-throwing overload returns static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(-1) on errors.` . But the value 18446744072617361848 is different from `static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(-1)`, so I am lost ....

My compiler is mingw32 :

```
mingw32-make.exe --version 
GNU Make 4.3 Built for Windows32 Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

I don't have the issue on linux (gcc).

Comment: If you set `std::uintmax_t filesize = -1;` (max value) and  the `SPDLOG_DEBUG("{}", filesize);` what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug that will be corrected in recent versions of MinGW. cf:

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95749

But event that, should replace

```
  size_t filesize;
```

by

```
std::uintmax_t filesize;
```

according the function's signature :

```
std::uintmax_t file_size( const std::filesystem::path& p );
```

Comment: That change nothing, I still have the same strange value.

Comment: note that  ```SPDLOG_DEBUG("std::uintmax_t {}, size_t {}", std::numeric_limits<std::uintmax_t>::max(), std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max())``` give me the same size for the two values : ```[07/12/2020 12:46:59][debug] std::uintmax_t 18446744073709551615, size_t 18446744073709551615```

Comment: It seems to be a bug of minGW32/64  https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/fina0q/msys2mingw64_stdfilesystem_file_size_large_file/

Answer (score 0):

`fs::file_size(filename);` returns a `std::uintmax_t`. Which is probably a 64bit integer. You assign that to a `size_t` which maybe (and probably is given your error) a 32 bit integer.

Just use a `uintmax_t`:

`uintmax_t filesize;`

Comment: That change nothing, I  still have the same strange value.

Comment: note that ```SPDLOG_DEBUG("std::uintmax_t {}, size_t {}", std::numeric_limits<std::uintmax_t>::max(), std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max())``` give me the same size for the two value : ```[07/12/2020 12:46:59][debug] std::uintmax_t 18446744073709551615, size_t 18446744073709551615```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug of MinGW32. The size you just got is a signed extension of 3202777528, you can check this value by yourself:

```
uint32_t real_file_size = 3202777528u; // roughly 3GB as you said
auto value_you_see = (uint64_t)(int32_t)real_file_size;
```

My guess is that MinGW32 uses ssize_t internally, which is an alias to int32_t in a 32-bits environment. Maybe you should use MinGW64 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like says by Florent, it seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/6585). [gcc 10.2 on windows](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/filesystem/ops-common.h#L66) use _wstat which is a 32 bits function. The correction will coming soon, in the version 10.3 of gcc on windows.